# I am not able to load the staticfiles in my templates. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to incorporate css in my templates to help them look better, but inspite of adding the static url and root, I am just not able to load it in my template. I am attaching the relevant code here. Please tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

settings.py

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
    STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = [STATIC_DIR,],
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<link href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_name/static')
   ]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<link href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

for more information [check here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: @Srvastav4 try this

Answer (score 0):

for loading static files you need to add the static url too

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    ......
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

add these in your project's root url

Comment: It gives me an error : + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) NameError: name 'static' is not defined

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
   ]. did you add this? and create a static folder in your root directory

Answer (score 0):

There is no settings named `STATIC_DIR`, it should be [**`STATICFILES_DIRS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) and should be declared like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'), 
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticroot')  # Static Dir and Static root needs to be different
```

As for serving static files, as per [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development), if you add `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, then django will serve static automatically when `DEBUG` is `True`. But in production, you need to use a reverse proxy server to static files. Or you can use [**`whitenoise`**](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/). More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/) as well.

Comment: It is still not working and when I try to put staticfiles dirs in my static root, It gives an error : File "/home/urvi/qwenv/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 378, in abspath
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Answer (score 0):

Change url base `urls.py` like following

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your url here
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Also include `{% load static %}` tag in your template

Comment: It gives me an error : + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
NameError: name 'static' is not defined

Comment: import this `from django.conf.urls.static import static`. Change `STATIC_ROOT = [STATIC_DIR,]` to `STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_URL `, and make sure `DEBUG=True`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Django do you using? Starting from 2.0 there are some changes, instead of

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```

there is

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

Also check out is your static folder even exist
And be sure that you have chosen right path to your static folder(for example I hold this folder inside of template folder so my code looks like this)

```
STATIC_URL = '/templates/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/static"),]
```

And I see that you didn't put csrf_token to your html, so please add this to your html

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: I am using django 2.1.0 and the path of static folder is correct. I tried with the templates directory but it still does not work at all. I am not using any form in that template so why csrf token?